# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 0

Tags: java, exception

I am working on a project and getting this error " java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 0" 
I've problem related to this, I know that this is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :P but 
taking look at this sample example,

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Oube {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

         list.add("Hello");
         list.add("World");
         list.add("World");

         System.out.println(list.size());
         System.out.println(list.get(0));
         System.out.println(list.get(1));
         System.out.println(list.get(2));
         System.out.println(list.get(3));
         System.out.println(list.get(4));
         System.out.println(list.get(5));
         System.out.println(list.get(6));
    }
}
```

we get following error,
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Here we don't see anything like, x<=y

and in my code, i amg etting 2>=0 error after ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
So my problem is that, when do we get such 2 >= 0 like errors ?

Comment: What is list.get(3) supposed to return ?

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an object of Arraylist whose size is dynamic

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

While you have only added 3 elements

```
list.add("Hello");
list.add("World");
list.add("World");
```

This creates an ArrayList of size 3 with index from 0 to 2. While calling from index greater than 2 as you have

```
 System.out.println(list.get(3));
 System.out.println(list.get(4));
 System.out.println(list.get(5));
 System.out.println(list.get(6));
```

you will receive an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are calling the elements whose index does not exist in ArrayList or the index is out of bound of ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

You added three item in list so size will be **3** but but index will  like this `0,1,2` now you want to get the `list.get(3)` etc then it will throwing the exception ,size is **3** and last element at position **2**. While if you will see your code

```
 System.out.println(list.get(3));
 System.out.println(list.get(4));
 System.out.println(list.get(5));
 System.out.println(list.get(6));
```

You are going to access those elements which is not present in the list ,so this exception is thrown when you try to access an array item that doesn't exist:

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the erorr in the form of

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
>
> Here we don't see anything like, x<=y

because Arraylist is a dynamic collection, which grows as per need. You get the mentioned exception when dealing with an array of fixed size.

all of these statements will throw exception because arraylist does not have elements at the desired index:

```
     System.out.println(list.get(3));
     System.out.println(list.get(4));
     System.out.println(list.get(5));
     System.out.println(list.get(6));
```

Answer (score 0):

All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown.

You make sure you're indices are within the range `[0...yourArray.length-1].`

so you are able to access 0,1,2